# Structure of mail box

Tags: database, database-design, erlang, database-schema, mnesia

I write simple pop3 server in erlang. Now i want to write mail box store with mnesia or something else databse. What's the most optimal structure of the tables and data-scheme for mail box?

Second question. I need advice for db, what do you think about mnesia for this point?

Thank you for your replyes.

And last question:

If i will use MAILDIR format or little mod of MAILDIR, where can i get information how mail clients for example thunderbird work with pop3 server with MAILDIR? Or it's not depend what mail store in the server, all client get mails with RETR num pop3 command?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Some comparisons of Mnesia to other database systems:

- [Mnesia versus MySQL, performance](http://www.ejabberd.im/node/3332)
- [CouchDB vs. Mnesia, vs. MySQL](http://ciarang.com/posts/couchdb-vs-mnesia-vs-mysql)

However I think plain filesystem is the best option to store user emails, because database servers add tangible overhead on CPU, memory and increase the complexity of the system. You may want to read about [Maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) e-mail format of storing e-mail messages, used by Cyrus IMAP, qmail, Courier, Dovecot etc.

Comment: I 2nd the idea of starting with a simple Maildir-format on disk and then extend it from there if needed. I would probably start with not storing anything on disk and then concentrate on all the other parts first. It is probably the case that the IO layer is nicely detachable from the rest of the system, so in a certain sense it is an easily solved problem.